# Drop multiple columns from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a `for` loop to remove multiple columns from multiple dataframes, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Everything inside the in parenthesis is a dataframe.

```
columns1 = ['Ano/Mes','Código da Grande Região','Código UF','Código do Município','Código CNAE','Admitidos-Demitidos','Tamanho em Jan/2020']

for cageds in (cagedjan,cagedfev,cagedmar,cagedabr,cagedmai,cagedjun,cagedjul):
    cageds = cageds.drop(cageds.columns[[5,6,7,8,10,11]], axis=1)
    cageds.columns = columns1
```

Edit: passing `inplace = True` is the solution.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Try using `df.drop` passing `inplace=True`

Comment: @ifly6 thanks. that worked!